# Printing a tree

Tags: java, tree, id3

I have written an ID3 and it prints the data. However, this is not very readable when the data sets become large. Is there any more human readable way this can be done?

Example of output given by the code below:

```
 if( Outlook == "Sunny") {
    if( Humidity == "High") {
            PlayTennis = "No";
    } else  if( Humidity == "Normal") {
            PlayTennis = "Yes";
    }
} else if( Outlook == "Overcast") {
        PlayTennis = "Yes";
} else if( Outlook == "Rain") {
    if( Wind == "Weak") {
            PlayTennis = "Yes";
    } else  if( Wind == "Strong") {
            PlayTennis = "No";
    }
}
```

I would ideally like to get a graph as follows from the above output:

[image]

Is there something I could use instead of these methods to give a tree automatically. The end goal is to analyse the tree depth etc?

Comment: What would more readable format look like to you? Are you looking for an alternate format or a library to use? What is the end goal once you have "readable" output?

Comment: a graphical representation would be ideal however I am very new to this so I do not know if there is something I could use instead of these methods to give a tree automatically. The end goal is to analyse the tree depth etc

Comment: I would find a graphic you think would be ideal and edit that image as well as your words above into the body of the question. It might be just finding a library that knows about the graphic view you seek... Hard to tell without an edit to refine what you want.

Comment: If console output works for you, you could just print out each node line by line, indenting it each time for every branch. Like a [directory structure](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/images/jboss_directory_structure.jpg). Not very user-friendly but very easy and no libraries needed.

Comment: can I export the output and use some library or anything to automatically get the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/treelayout/

It is the layout code used by antlr and seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I have to install netbeans for this?

Comment: No you dont.  You just need java which include Swing.  But in any case an IDE is great for developing Java.  I like eclipse myself.

Comment: i am using BlueJ... do you know if it has Swing? Since I cannot find a way to check

Comment: I am trying to understand the link you gave me but there is no examples of the source code needed to create such a tree. Can you explain further what needs to be done please?

Comment: I recommended this because it is what antlr uses  and it graphically outputs a tree quite nicely.   The class in antlr that uses it is the TreeViewer class.  You can search for TreeViewer.java antlr source, or try this: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/gui/TreeViewer.java.  It does seem like layout is not well documented, but the TreeViewer class looks pretty simple.

Comment: BLuej is just an IDE for java, so yes it has swing, but I'n not sure if it provides  any  specific  support for swing. Not sure  if you need it though. Eclipse doesn't provide support either.